# Rename column names as per names in dataframe in R

Tags: r

Is there a way to rename column names in R as per values in Dataframe

```
df
ColA   ColB
1      3
2      4
```

These above column names should be renamed. But I have these in another dataframe below

```
df_1
D         Z
ColA      New_ColA
ColB      New_ColB
```

Expected output (so with reference to df_1 dataframe, the column names needs to be changed)

```
df
New_ColA   New_ColB
1           3
2           4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `match` -

```
names(df) <- df_1$Z[match(names(df), df_1$D)]
df

#  New_ColA New_ColB
#1        1        3
#2        2        4
```

Or the same logic using `rename_with` in `dplyr` -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% rename_with(~df_1$Z[match(., df_1$D)])
```